# Sound feedback on panel's volumen indicator

Tags: gnome, sound, gnome-panel

Is there a way to have a sound feedback when increasing or decreasing the sound volumen in the panel widget?

[image]

Ubuntu version:
$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

GNOME version:

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.9
```

GNOME Extensions installed:

```
$ gnome-extensions list
system-monitor@paradoxxx.zero.gmail.com
dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com
wintile@nowsci.com
alt-tab-workspace@kwalo.net
switcher@landau.fi
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
workspaces-bar@fthx
```